# gstreamer 1.0 videosink stays paused

Tags: gstreamer

I have the following pipeline in C to play video files: `filesrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink`, after getting EOS signal, I try to modify the pipeline to show images (gapless):

```
gst_element_set_state(player->src, GST_STATE_READY); // filesrc

gst_element_set_state(player->vid_bin, GST_STATE_NULL); // decodebin
gst_element_unlink(player->src, player->vid_bin);
gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN (player->pipe), player->vid_bin);

gst_bin_add(GST_BIN (player->pipe), player->img_bin); // bin: jpegdec ! imagefreeze
gst_element_link_many(player->src, player->img_bin, player->video_out, NULL);

g_object_set(G_OBJECT (player->src), "location", next.path.c_str(), NULL);
gst_element_set_state(player->img_bin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
gst_element_set_state(player->src, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
gst_element_set_state(player->video_out, GST_STATE_PLAYING); // bin: videoconvert ! glimagesink

GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE_WITH_TS (GST_BIN (player->pipe), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "gst-play.eos.final");
```

But there is no output in the window. the graph of the pipeline shows that the glimagesink is in the paused state. Could it be the reason for missing output and how to fix it? Setting the pipeline to ready state at the beginning and to play state at the end works, but leads to a gap that I would like to avoid.

[image]

Comment: what about calling `gst_element_sync_state_with_parent` and then just set the pipe to playing instead of manualy setting to PLAYING..

Comment: does not help, I guess after the eos event traveled down the pipe all element did deinit all ressources.

Comment: in that case you can add [pad probe](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-dataaccess.html) to catch the EOS, maybe its something similar to [dynamicaly changing pipeline](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html) which is not very easy..

Comment: this is what I actually do. I add a GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_DOWNSTREAM probe to the videosink and wait for EOS, passing everything else. On EOS event I drop it and modify the pipeline, call gst_pad_set_offset to keep the time line synced, but there is still no video output. Setting decodebin to GST_STATE_NULL makes for some reason the pipeline go to PAUSED state. However after bringing it back to PLAY state, the GstGLImageSink (and only this part of glimagesink) stays paused like on the graph

Comment: what about ximagesink/xvimagesink ?

Comment: X-server is not installed on the target, on the dev Mac I tried osxvideosink with same result - it is paused. maybe there is something wrong with the pad offset calculation, will check it.

Comment: Got it working finally. pad offset of the videosink has to be set before changing the state of decodebin and removing it from the pipeline. And also important to unlink it's src pad from the sink pad of glimagesink before setting pad offset.

Comment: very interesting, you can add it as answer and accept it, I am sure it will help somebody..

Comment: seems that it works not reliable, especially on the raspberry Pi. The offset is sometimes to small.  I think it would be cleaner to generate a new segment, but I could not find an example how to do it the right way to get it working.